# Clearing memory allocated by vector

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I used the followed code and the gnome system monitor to view how memory is allocated into the memory:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;

int main(void)
{


string sentence;
std::vector<string>words{};


string seperators{" ,:;!."};


std::cout<<"Please enter the line terminated by an asterisk"<<std::endl;

std::getline(std::cin, sentence, '*');


std::cout<<"The sentence is: "<<sentence<<std::endl;
size_t start{0};
size_t end{};
int count{};
while(start != string::npos)
{

    end = sentence.find_first_of(seperators, start + 1);

    string word = sentence.substr(start, end - start);

    std::cout<<word<<std::endl;

    words.push_back(word);

    start = sentence.find_first_not_of(seperators, end +1);

    if(count++ == 10000000)
    {
        std::cout<<"^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"<<"here"<<std::endl;
        break;
    }
}


words.clear();
//for(auto word: words)
//{
//    std::cout<<word <<std::endl;
   // }

std::cin>>start;

}
```

As the while loop continues, the memory consumption meter starts to increase continuously at a steady rate, and after the loop breaks on reaching a count of 10000000, the program executes the words.clear() function, which should had cleared out, but, it doesn't. The memory say, reaches 53% consumed, until the program ends.

If .clear() is not the way to free memory accumulated by the vector, then, how do we free it? It should'd been done automatically, but my experiment shows that it wasn't. Or, is this something wrong with the code?

Comment: Memory once allocated in a process isn't returned to the OS. The freed memory is available inside of the process though.

Comment: To add to the previous comment by @user0042, if the system gets low on memory the operating system *can* unmap the memory from the process to give to another process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call clear, and that will destroy all the objects, but that will not free the memory. Looping through the individual elements will not help either (what action would you even propose to take on the objects?) What you can do is this:

```
vector<tempObject>().swap(tempVector);
```

That will create an empty vector with no memory allocated and swap it with tempVector, effectively deallocating the memory.

C++11 also has the function shrink_to_fit, which you could call after the call to clear(), and it would theoretically shrink the capacity to fit the size (which is now 0). This is however, a non-binding request, and your implementation is free to ignore it.

Comment: By the way, notice that having `clear` not freeing any memory is actually a feature, because when you reuse the vector later it doesn't have to perform any more allocation. It actually happened to me several times to get significant speedups by moving an `std::string` outside of a loop and calling `clear` instead of re-creating it at each iteration.

Comment: yes it is a feature but OP asked question on how to free memory :)

Comment: Of course, and in facts I upvoted your answer. I was just trying to explain to OP what is the rationale of this choice.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`shrink_to_fit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) (a C++11 addition) after `clear()` to free the unused memory reserved by `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but could you please add why would then we use vector, when the memory is not freed?

Comment: It *is* freed on destruction. `clear()` just means "logically delete the existing elements".

Comment: @MatteoItalia, Meaning it's deallocated but persistent in memory?(I don't really understand that)

Comment: No, it means that the destructor is called over the elements, but the backing storage is not deallocated. The vector `size()` shrinks to zero, but its `capacity()` stays the same, which means that, if you start doing `push_back` again the vector won't have to reallocate anything until at least you hit its previous size. This is often a big win if you are recycling the vector e.g. between iterations of a loop, because it means that you avoid keeping allocating and deallocating the vector data, once it grows to its maximum size the allocator isn't invoked again (until the actual destruction).